# Estimate size of xml file

Tags: xml, xsd, filesize

I have an the `xsd schema` for the layout of an `xml file`, is there any way I can use this schema to estimate a range of how big `xml` files generated from this `xsd` wil be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. Except for a few very unusual schemas, e.g. a schema that doesn't use maxOccurs="unbounded" and that applies a maxLength constraint to every string.

Comment: the schema that i am using does do that.

Comment: @jgr208, mentioning such a remarkable property and including a representative sample of your XSD in your question would be a good idea.

Comment: @kjhughes I am using the two following xsd which define a simica xml file, http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1636/1636.1-2007/Common.xsd and http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1636/1636.1-2007/TestResults.xsd

Comment: as of note the ones that are marked unbounded we figured out what they should be bounded to and bounded them to 3 in our xsd file